# How can I make sure 100% that the backgroundworker is not busy and then start it over again?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a button click event where I make once some Lists and start the backgroundworker1:

```
private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnDownload.Enabled = false;
            label7.Text = "Downloading...";
            ei.Init();
            if (countryList.Count() == 0)
            {
                foreach (ExtractImages.Continent continent in ei.world.continents)
                {
                    foreach (ExtractImages.Country country in continent.countries)
                    {
                        if (country.name == "Israel")
                        {
                            foreach (string imageUri in country.imageUrls)
                            {
                                countryList.Add(imageUri);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            foreach (string imageUri in country.imageUrls)
                            {
                                newList.Add(imageUri);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

In the dowork event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {

            if (downloaded == false)
            {
                getTotalBytes(countryList);
                CreateCountryDateTimeDirectories(countryList);
                downloadFile(countryList);
            }
            else
            {
                getTotalBytes(newList);
                CreateCountryDateTimeDirectories(newList);
                downloadFile(newList);
            }
        }
```

In the dowork event I have two phases first it will make calculations and will download the links in the List countryList.

What I want to do is once it finish to download all the link in countryLinks start backgroundworker1 over again and this time download the links in the List newList.

This is how l'm downloading the links in the List.

```
private Queue<string> _downloadUrls = new Queue<string>();

        private int urlCount = 0; // keep track of how many urls are processed

        private async void downloadFile(IEnumerable<string> urls)
        {
            urlCount = 0;
            foreach (var url in urls)
            {
                _downloadUrls.Enqueue(url);
                urlCount++;
            }
            // urlCount is now set
            await DownloadFile();
        }

        private async Task DownloadFile()
        {
            if (_downloadUrls.Any())
            {
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += ProgressChanged;
                client.DownloadFileCompleted += Completed;

                var url = _downloadUrls.Dequeue();

                sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

                if (url.Contains("true"))
                {
                    await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(url), @"c:\temp\TempSatFiles\" + urlCount + "Infrared.jpg");
                    //await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(url), countriesMainPath + "\\" + currentDownloadCountry + "\\" + urlCount + "Infrared.jpg");
                }
                else
                {
                    await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(url), @"c:\temp\TempSatFiles\" + urlCount + "Invisible.jpg");
                    //await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(url), countriesMainPath + "\\" + currentDownloadCountry + "\\" + urlCount + "Invisible.jpg");
                }

                return;
            }
        }

        double percentageTotalDownload = 0;
        double totalBytesDownloaded = 0;
        private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Calculate download speed and output it to labelSpeed.
            label3.Text = string.Format("{0} kb/s", (e.BytesReceived / 1024d / sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString("0.00"));

            // Update the progressbar percentage only when the value is not the same.
            double bytesInCurrentDownload = (double)e.BytesReceived;
            double totalBytesCurrentDownload = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
            double percentageCurrentDownload = bytesInCurrentDownload / totalBytesCurrentDownload * 100;
            ProgressBar1.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentageCurrentDownload).ToString());//e.ProgressPercentage;
                                                                                                // Show the percentage on our label.
            Label4.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";

            // Update the label with how much data have been downloaded so far and the total size of the file we are currently downloading
            label10.Text = string.Format("{0} MB's / {1} MB's",
                (e.BytesReceived / 1024d / 1024d).ToString("0.00"),
                (e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024d / 1024d).ToString("0.00"));

            //Let's update ProgressBar2
            totalBytesDownloaded = e.BytesReceived + bytesFromCompletedFiles;
            percentageTotalDownload = totalBytesDownloaded / totalBytesToDownload * 100;
            progressBar2.Value = (int)percentageTotalDownload;
            label6.Text = progressBar2.Value.ToString() + "%";
        }

        long bytesFromCompletedFiles = 0;
        private async void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var cnt = System.Threading.Interlocked.Decrement(ref urlCount);

            if (cnt > 0)
            {
                await DownloadFile();
                label9.Text = urlCount.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                label7.Text = "Download completed";
                downloaded = true;
                btnDownload.Enabled = true;
                sw.Stop();
            }
        }
```

Now it will download the links in countryList.
When it finish download all the files in the List it will get to the else part:

```
label7.Text = "Download completed";
downloaded = true;
btnDownload.Enabled = true;
sw.Stop();
```

Here i want to restart the backgroundworker1 and this time in the dowork event it will download the links in the newList.

The problem is how do I know that the backgroundworker1 is not busy ? There might be a situation that it downloaded the all the files and the backgroundworker1 is still busy ?

Or maybe I should start the backgroundworker in the completed event of the backgroundworker ? If it finished all the downloads it will then get to the backgroundworker completed event ? or first it will get to the webclient completed event ?

Comment: Managing multiple `BackgroundWorker`s is always awkward; it's one of the signs that your code is ready to [upgrade from BGW to `Task.Run`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the worker is busy or not by using...

```
if(!backgroundworker1 .IsBusy)
  backgroundworker1 .RunWorkerAsync();
```

No, if you've properly checked when it finishes then the worker will finish on when the downloading completes, it can be busy when it will wait for response and the response doesn't come soon.
Yes, when worker completes it work, it is recommended(from my side) to start it again to perform some other tasks.
Yes whenever it will finish, the completed event will be fired.
the event of webclient is inside the backgroundworker event, webclient completed event will be first. You've to debug your code first to see the sequential flow of your code.